# How can user modify color, page and title in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to create a single page website using ROR which allows the users to modify the styling of that page. At a minimum, the user should be able to change the colors, title, and font on the page, but should not be able to modify the controls for styling the page. Data should be saved via ActiveRecord and changes should persist sessions.

My question: I have created here form for user and created three field inside user table i.e font, background color and title and using devise for authentication, but then how can I save font, title and style for users so that the changes should reflect in pages and the changes should persist with session.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    end
```

static_page.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user do |u| %>
      <p>
        <%= u.label :title %><br>
        <%= u.text_field :title %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= u.label :description %><br>
        <%= u.text_field :description %>
      </p>

      <p> <%= u.label :back_ground_color %><br>
        <select name="back-ground" id="bgcolor">
            <option value="1">Orange</option>
            <option value="2">Green</option>
            <option value="3">Blue</option>
            <option value="4">Pink</option>
            <option value="5">Yellow</option>
            <option value="6">White</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= u.label :font %><br>
        <select name="font" id="font">
            <option value="1">Times new Roman</option>
            <option value="2">Calibri</option>
            <option value="3">fantasy</option>
            <option value="4">serif</option>
        </select>
      </p>
     <br >
      <p>
        <%= u.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

**Now what should I do to submit this form so that it should work**
Don't forget - I need to change the background color, font, title and as well as stored in database for persistence.

Comment: If some one is voting down the question then pls let me know the reason also in comment, so that I can improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the color's hexadecimal value (eg: #FFFFFF) in the database. Then in the view either you can give inline css or you can use the helper to generate it like this:

```
content_tag(:span, "",  :style => "background-color:#{current_user.font_color}")
```

You can use the inline css in the same way. And in the same way you can do it for font and other things. Like storing the font name like this: `"Times New Roman"` and then specifying it in the `font-family`. Use these dynamic names everywhere and you can always have a default value if someone doesn't enters any value then like this:

```
content_tag(:span, "", :style => "background-color:#{current_user.font_color.nil? ? '#FFFFFF' : current_user.font_color}")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need to write a JS also for taking value from the user and reflecting the changes. let me know also once I click the form submit then which page it should go

Comment: No just save this value in database. And in the view which you are using for the user to display the details specify this css instead of static css. Fetch the values from database rather than specifying them explicitly. This is a very simple thing you are just getting a bit confused. You can do this thing easily.

Comment: Can I have your email id ? This is bit urgent so need your help in that

Comment: On stackoverflow people can only help you and not write code for you.. so you can just let people know the code where you are facing issues so they can correct you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75497/discussion-between-cyborg-and-deep).